# Create session factory in Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having trouble generating a session factory in Hibernate 4. In Hibernate 3 I simple did:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration conf= HibernateUtil
    .getLimsInitializedConfiguration(systemConfiguration
.getHibernateconfFile());

SessionFactory sf = conf.configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Now I need to pass a ServiceRegistry class to buildSessionFactory, but the Javadocs are extremely vague on how to go about this. Any tips?

Comment: possible duplicate , refer to 'Is buildSessionFactory() deprecated in hibernate 4?'


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621906/is-buildsessionfactory-deprecated-in-hibernate-4

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes, they have deprecated the previous buildSessionFactory API, and it's quite easy to do well.. you can do something like this..

**EDIT** : ServiceRegistryBuilder is deprecated. you must use StandardServiceRegistryBuilder

```
public void testConnection() throws Exception {

            logger.info("Trying to create a test connection with the database.");
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate_sp.cfg.xml");
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            logger.info("Test connection with the database created successfuly.");
    }
```

For more reference and in depth detail, you can check the hibernate's official test case at https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-testing/src/main/java/org/hibernate/testing/junit4/BaseCoreFunctionalTestCase.java function (buildSessionFactory()).

Comment: Apparently the type "ServiceRegistryBuilder" is now deprecated.  Any updates on how to do this while avoiding deprecated code?

Comment: Use StandardServiceRegistryBuilder instead.

Answer (score 18):

Try this!

```
package your.package;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static
    {
        try
        {
//          Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch (HibernateException he)
        {
            System.err.println("Error creating Session: " + he);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I love when people show imports, makes me all fuzzy inside as well as making sure I have the correct namespaces.

Answer (score 11):

```
Configuration hibConfiguration = new Configuration()
            .addResource("wp4core/hibernate/config/table.hbm.xml")
            .configure();       

serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(hibConfiguration.getProperties())
            .buildServiceRegistry();

sessionFactory = hibConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
session = sessionFactory.withOptions().openSession();
```

Answer (score 7):

The following expresses the experience I had with hibernate 4.0.0.Final.

The javadoc (distributed under LGPL license) of `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` class states that:

> NOTE : This will be replaced by use of `ServiceRegistryBuilder` and
>    `org.hibernate.metamodel.MetadataSources` instead after the 4.0 release at which point this class will become deprecated and scheduled for removal in 5.0.  See [HHH-6183](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-6183), [HHH-2578](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2578) and
>   [HHH-6586](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-6586) for details

After looking at issue 2578, i used something like this:

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().buildServiceRegistry();
MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
metadataSources.addResource("some_mapping.hbm.xml")
SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadataSources.buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
```

For it to start reading configuration, i had to modify my hibernate 3.2.6 configuration and mapping files to use `xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"` and `xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping"` and also remove the dtd specifications.

I couldn't find a way for it to inspect mappings defined in hibernate.cfg.xml and   *hibernate.* prefix for hibernate-related properties in *hibernate.cfg.xml* is no longer optional.

This might work for some.

I, for one, ran into some error because mapping files contained `<cache usage="read-write" />` and ended up using deprecated Configuration way:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImpl) configuration.buildSessionFactory();
EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
SolrIndexEventListener indexListener = new SolrIndexEventListener(); // a SaveOrUpdateEventListener i wanted to attach
listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.SAVE_UPDATE, indexListener);
```

I had to programatically append event listeners because Configuration no longer looks for them in hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: MetadataSources is what you will use starting in 5.0 (*after* 4.0).  The correct solution is more along the lines of ZE pixota's answer.  Event listeners are expected to be handled by implementations of org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator

Answer (score 4):

Even there is an update in 4.3.0 API. ServiceRegistryBuilder is also deprecated in 4.3.0 and replaced with the StandardServiceRegistryBuilder. Now the actual code for creating the session factory would look this [example on creating session factory](http://www.javabeat.net/session-factory-hibernate-4/).

Comment: Thanks, all the other answers I saw on this thread are deprecated

Answer (score 2):

[quote from http://www.javabeat.net/session-factory-hibernate-4/]

There are many APIs deprecated in the hibernate core framework. One of the frustrating point at this time is, hibernate official documentation is not providing the clear instructions on how to use the new API and it stats that the documentation is in complete. Also each incremental version gets changes on some of the important API. One such thing is the new API for creating the session factory in Hibernate 4.3.0 on wards. In our earlier versions we have created the session factory as below:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

**The method buildSessionFactory is deprecated from the hibernate 4 release** and it is replaced with the new API. If you are using the hibernate 4.3.0 and above, your code has to be:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```

**Class ServiceRegistryBuilder is  replaced by StandardServiceRegistryBuilder from 4.3.0.** It looks like there will be lot of changes in the 5.0 release. Still there is not much clarity on the deprecated APIs and the suitable alternatives to use. Every incremental release comes up with more deprecated API, they are in way of fine tuning the core framework for the release 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions session factory was created as below:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

The method buildSessionFactory is deprecated from the hibernate 4 release and it is replaced with the new API. If you are using the hibernate 4.3.0 and above, your code has to be like:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `buildSessionFactory` is deprecated from the Hibernate 4 release and it is replaced with the new API. If you are using the Hibernate 4.3.0 and above, your code has to be:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```