# Is the buildSessionFactory() Configuration method deprecated in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, deprecated, bootstrapping

When I updated the Hibernate version from 3.6.8 to 4.0.0, I got a warning about deprecated method `buildSessionFactory()` in this line:

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory =
         new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

the Javadoc recommends using another method

`buildSessionFactory(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)`

but in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-sessionfactory) I found deprecated variant

Comment: Even in 4.3.8 quick start guide they are using this example: new Configuration()       .configure().buildSessionFactory(); :(

Comment: @VenkataRaju May be, it is not bad, because of in Hibernate 5 everything turn back and this example correct, but (!) all configuration examples here are [not valid for Hibernate 5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32711654/3405171).

Answer (score 385, accepted):

Yes it is deprecated. Replace your SessionFactory with the following:

In **Hibernate 4.0, 4.1, 4.2**

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()). buildServiceRegistry();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

> **UPDATE:**

In **Hibernate 4.3** ServiceRegistryBuilder is **deprecated**. Use the following instead.

```
serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();
```

Comment: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder is also depracated!

Comment: Yes, it seems ServiceRegistryBuilder is itself deprecated, looking at the documentation, they suggest using StandardServiceRegistryBuilder instead.  So I guess the call should now be new StandardRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

Comment: I can't find StandardRegistryBuilder in hibernate 4.3 could it be that it was changed there?

Comment: Instead of build() one needs buildServiceRegistry(), right? I can't find ServiceRegistry.build().

Comment: It seems its the mission of the hibernate team to deprecate everything they create.

Comment: **Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
   configuration.configure();
   ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
     configuration.getProperties()).build();
   return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);** generates java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider

Comment: @gstackoverflow
`SessionFactory sessionFactory;
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
Configuration config = new Configuration();
…
sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();`

Worked for me

Comment: UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
  user.setUserId(1);
  user.setUserName("user1");
  
  Configuration config = new Configuration();
  config.configure();
  
  ServiceRegistry  serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
  sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
  
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  session.save(user);
  session.getTransaction().commit();

Comment: THANK YOU!  The code suggested in the Hibernate 4.2 Tutorial actually uses StandardServiceRegistryBuilder, which is not included in any version of hibernate-core before v 4.3. Your code snippet was very useful.

Comment: Please use hibernate 4.3 for StandardStandardServiceRegistryBuilder class

Comment: It worked well for me, I am using Hibernate 4.3.1, Thank you :-)

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is deprecated.  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#buildSessionFactory() specifically tells you to use the other method you found instead (`buildSessionFactory(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)`) - so use it.

The documentation is copied over from release to release, and likely just hasn't been updated yet (they don't rewrite the manual with every release) - so trust the Javadocs.

The specifics of this change can be viewed at:

- Source code: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/commit/0b10334e403cf2b11ee60725cc5619eaafecc00b
- Ticket: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5991

Some additional references:

- http://relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateCore40IsFinal
- http://relation.to/19942.lace
- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch07.html#services-registry
- http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/hibernate/index.php?title=Category:Services

Comment: so how do we make sessions now ? what is the object that is assigned to serviceRegistry interface ??

Comment: @IsmailMarmoush - I haven't played with this too much yet, but have added some additional references.

Answer (score 8):

or

```
public class Hbutil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return configureSessionFactory();

    }
}
```

Comment: Some deprecated methods are being used in this code.

Answer (score 6):

Code verified to work in Hibernate 4.3.0. Notice you can remove the XML filename parameter, or else provide your own path there.  This is similar to (but typos corrected) other posts here, but this one is correct.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;    


Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("/com/rtw/test/hiber/hibernate.cfg.xml");
ServiceRegistry  serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();        
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple as this: the JBoss docs are not 100% perfectly well-maintained. Go with [what the JavaDoc says](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#buildSessionFactory%28org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry%29): `buildSessionFactory(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)`.

Answer (score 4):

It is not unusual to find discrepancies between different versions of documentation.  Most developers view documentation as a chore, and they tend to put it off.

As a rule of thumb, if the javadoc says one thing and some non-javadoc documentation contradicts it, the chances are that the javadoc is more accurate.  Programmers are more likely to keep the javadoc up to date with changes to the code ... because the "source" for the javadoc is in the same file as the code.

In the case of `@deprecated` tags, it is a virtual certainty that the javadoc is more accurate.  Developers deprecate things after careful consideration ... and (generally speaking) they don't undeprecate them.

Comment: *...and they don't undeprecate them.* ... unless it's called `System.getenv(String)` http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4199068

Comment: It's not unusual to find crap projects, whose lazy developers don't bother about keeping the documentation aligned with the code, so that they drive their users crazy, while these try to figure out how the bloody rubbish works by rummaging in itself and hoping there is something more than /** TODO: comment-me */ :-\

Comment: @bestsss ...or it's called `Configuration.buildSessionFactory()` ;)

Answer (score 4):

A better way to create **SessionFactory** object in Latest hibernate release **4.3.0** onward is as follow:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```

Comment: getting error: The method buildSessionFactory() in the type Configuration is not applicable for the arguments (StandardServiceRegistry)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Hibernate 5.2** and above then you can use this:

```
  private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
      try {
        // Creating a registry
        registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();

        // Create the MetadataSources
        MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

        // Create the Metadata
        Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

        // Create SessionFactory
        sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (registry != null) {
          StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
      }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  //To shut down
 public static void shutdown() {
    if (registry != null) {
      StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Yes, it is. There are better ways to bootstrap Hibernate, like the following ones.

### Hibernate-native bootstrap

The legacy `Configuration` object is less powerful than using the `BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder`, introduced since Hibernate 4:

```
final BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder bsrb = new BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder()
    .enableAutoClose();

Integrator integrator = integrator();
if (integrator != null) {
    bsrb.applyIntegrator( integrator );
}

final BootstrapServiceRegistry bsr = bsrb.build();

final StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = 
    new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder(bsr)
        .applySettings(properties())
        .build();

final MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);

for (Class annotatedClass : entities()) {
    metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(annotatedClass);
}

String[] packages = packages();
if (packages != null) {
    for (String annotatedPackage : packages) {
        metadataSources.addPackage(annotatedPackage);
    }
}

String[] resources = resources();
if (resources != null) {
    for (String resource : resources) {
        metadataSources.addResource(resource);
    }
}

final MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder = metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder()
    .enableNewIdentifierGeneratorSupport(true)
    .applyImplicitNamingStrategy(ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl.INSTANCE);

final List<Type> additionalTypes = additionalTypes();
if (additionalTypes != null) {
    additionalTypes.stream().forEach(type -> {
        metadataBuilder.applyTypes((typeContributions, sr) -> {
            if(type instanceof BasicType) {
                typeContributions.contributeType((BasicType) type);
            } else if (type instanceof UserType ){
                typeContributions.contributeType((UserType) type);
            } else if (type instanceof CompositeUserType) {
                typeContributions.contributeType((CompositeUserType) type);
            }
        });
    });
}

additionalMetadata(metadataBuilder);

MetadataImplementor metadata = (MetadataImplementor) metadataBuilder.build();

final SessionFactoryBuilder sfb = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder();
Interceptor interceptor = interceptor();
if(interceptor != null) {
    sfb.applyInterceptor(interceptor);
}

SessionFactory sessionFactory = sfb.build();
```

### JPA bootstrap

You can also bootstrap Hibernate using JPA:

```
PersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnitInfo = persistenceUnitInfo(getClass().getSimpleName());
Map configuration = properties();

Interceptor interceptor = interceptor();
if (interceptor != null) {
    configuration.put(AvailableSettings.INTERCEPTOR, interceptor);
}

Integrator integrator = integrator();
if (integrator != null) {
    configuration.put(
        "hibernate.integrator_provider", 
        (IntegratorProvider) () -> Collections.singletonList(integrator));
}

EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl entityManagerFactoryBuilder = 
    new EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl(
        new PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor(persistenceUnitInfo), 
        configuration
);
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactoryBuilder.build();
```

This way, you are building the `EntityManagerFactory` instead of a `SessionFactory`. However, the `SessionFactory` extends the `EntityManagerFactory, so the actual object that's built is a`SessionFactoryImpl` too.

### Conclusion

These two bootstrapping methods affect Hibernate behavior. When using the native bootstrap, Hibernate behaves in the legacy mode, which predates JPA.

When bootstrapping using JPA, Hibernate will behave according to the JPA specification.

There are several differences between these two modes:

- [How the AUTO flush mode works in regards to native SQL queries](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-the-auto-flush-work-in-jpa-and-hibernate/)
- How the entity Proxy is built. Traditionally, Hibernate did not hit the DB when building a Proxy, but JPA requires throwing an `EntityNotFoundException`, therefore demanding a DB check.
- whether you can delete a non-managed entity

> For more details about these differences, check out the [`JpaCompliance`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpa/spi/JpaCompliance.java) class.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory1();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory1() {
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(); // configuration
                                                                // settings
                                                                // from
                                                                // hibernate.cfg.xml

StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();


serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();

return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
return sessionFactory;
 }

public static void shutdown() {
// Close caches and connection pools
getSessionFactory().close();
 }
```

Comment: 'StandardServiceRegistryBuilder' is also deprecated.

Comment: @NitinRam `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder` is NOT deprecated.

Comment: Quite weird how things are taken on and off deprecation in Hibernate. It used to be at one point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911308/looking-for-a-not-deprecated-session-factory

Answer (score 1):

If anyone here after updating to 5.1 this is how it works

```
StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
```

instead of the below in hibernate 4.3

```
 ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()). buildServiceRegistry();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Answer (score 0):

public void sampleConnection() throws Exception {

```
     Configuration cfg = new Configuration().addResource("hibernate.cfg.xml").configure();
     StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
     SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
     Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
     logger.debug(" connection with the database created successfuly.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited the method created by [batbaatar above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621906/is-buildsessionfactory-deprecated-in-hibernate-4/8830848#8830848) so it accepts the Configuration object as a parameter:

```
    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory(Configuration configuration) {
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return factory;
    }
```

In the main class I did:

```
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    private static Configuration configuration 
    ...      
    configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure().addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class);
    // Other configurations, then           
    factory = createSessionFactory(configuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Hibernate 4.2.2**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
            .configure();

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    Users users = new Users();

    ... ...

    session.save(users);

    transaction.commit();

    session.close();

    sessionFactory.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Tested on 4.2.7 release

package com.national.software.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

import com.national.software.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

    static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("user1");

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.configure();

        ServiceRegistry  serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here are many APIs deprecated in the hibernate core framework.

we have created the session factory as below:

SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

The method buildSessionFactory is deprecated from the hibernate 4 release and it is replaced with the new API. If you are using the hibernate 4.3.0 and above, your code has to be:

1. Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
2. StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
3. SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

Class ServiceRegistryBuilder is  replaced by StandardServiceRegistryBuilder from 4.3.0. It looks like there will be lot of changes in the 5.0 release. Still there is not much clarity on the deprecated APIs and the suitable alternatives to use. Every incremental release comes up with more deprecated API, they are in way of fine tuning the core framework for the release 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

In `hibernate 5.3.1`, you can try this:

```
ServiceRegistry standardRegistry = 
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

Metadata sources = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).addAnnotatedClass(MyEntity.class).getMetadataBuilder().build();

SessionFactory sf = sources.buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just import following package,

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
```