# buildSessionFactory() method that return Hibernate SessionFactory object is deprecated, how to solve?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I am new in Hibernate and I am studying this ORM framework reading this article: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm

I have read all the previous Hibernate tutorial of this site and until now it is all pretty clear for me.

The only "problem" is that I am not using Hibernate 3.6.4-Final (as is used in this tutorials series) but I am using the last Hibernate **4.1.9-Final** version.

I have implement this example and work well but Eclipse say me that an instruction of the main class **ManageEmployee** are deprechated.

The deprecated instruction is the calling of **buildSessionFactory()** following one:

```
factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`
```

How can I replace it to create a new factory that is not deprecated?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621906/is-buildsessionfactory-deprecated-in-hibernate-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hibernate 4, buildSessionFactory( ) is deprecated. This example contains code which you can use in spite of buildSessionFactory ().

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

You can get more details at [Hibernate 4 Simple Example](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/Hibernate4Example.shtml)

Comment: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder is also deprecated!