# Force Hibernate To Create Tables After Dropping and Recreating database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am developing a web application with java 2 ee. I also use hibernate and mysql.
in order to restore the backup file, in some point in my application i need to drop the current database and recreate it, i do it as follow :

```
    Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=user&password=pass");
    Statement statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate("DROP DATABASE tcs;");
    statement.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE tcs charset=utf8 collate=utf8_persian_ci;");
```

after dropping and recreating i need to initialize database with default user (spring security user)

```
    User admin = new User();
    UserAuthority ROLE_USER = new UserAuthority("ROLE_USER");
    ROLE_USER.save();
    admin.addUserAuthority(ROLE_USER);
    admin.setEnabled(true);

    admin.save();
```

but at the last line application throws this exception

```
Hibernate: insert into roles (authority) values (?)
[DEBUG][16:19:17,734] [http-bio-8080-exec-10] NewPooledConnection:367  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@bcbe33a handling a throwable.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'tcs.roles' doesn't exist
```

i know hibernate creates tables at startup but in this case it fails to recreate the tables after a drop/recreate , so how can i force hibernate to create tables again? 
or hypothetically is there something like `Hibernate.createTable(Class)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for future googlers :
it was so simple after all , i just needed to build session factory so i added this line and it worked like charm :

new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

note that  `buildSessionFactory()` is deprecated in hibernate 4 but i guess you can use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621906/is-buildsessionfactory-deprecated-in-hibernate-4) to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the following property to your configuration:

Drop and Recreate everytime SessionFactory is created and destroyed:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
```

Other possible options:

- validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- update: update the schema.
- create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.

Comment: isnt this line drops and creates on every start up?

Comment: Nah, still the same issue.

Comment: it is already update, it works in startup but not when runnig, i need to some how trigger it again

Comment: In that case, your database may be in an inconsistent state. Drop the database for once and try it again. `update` can handle the subsequent restarts

Comment: i tried it, not working, maybe hibernate doesn't support it after all