# createDatabaseIfNotExist=true not working in .properties file in maven project

Tags: java, database, hibernate, maven, jdbc

I have a maven project that connects to a database that already exists. however i wanted to change it so that if the database doesn't already exist. it gets created. so i added in this extra code `?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` to this line.

`dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/rays-database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`

And i got a lot of errors, so my question is; is there any extra configuration that im missing in order to use ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

I also tried adding the port number which didn't make any difference which i didn't expect it to.

```
dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rays-database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

here is my .properties file:

```
 dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/rays-database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
 dataSource.username=root
 dataSource.password=

 hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
 hibernate.show_sql=true
 hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

Comment: Long shot but which version of the mysql JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply @Tunaki i am using 5.1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this [Why is Hibernate not creating database for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632954/why-is-hibernate-not-creating-database-for-mysql). Hope it helps.What kind of errors you are getting?

Comment: I have updated my question with the .properties file. seems pretty much the same.

Comment: i get errors like, something to do with memory leak, and something wrong with my sql syntax, Error creating bean with name 'configureDataSource'

Comment: Replace hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect 
with
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Comment: i added the 5 to the dialect but still no change

Comment: WARNING: The web application [/RaysRentalSystem] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:

Comment: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-database' at line 1

Comment: remove '-' from rays-database in  dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/rays-database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one, you have to add port and delete this(-) on the db name.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DbName?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```