# Looking for a not-deprecated session-factory

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations, sessionfactory, sql-server-2012-express

I am dealing with hibernate and as I opened my current project I figured out my Session-Factory is deprecated:

```
AnnotationConfiguration af = new AnnotationConfiguration();
SessionFactory factory = af.configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = factory.openSession();
```

AnnotationConfiguration seems to be deprecated by now... So I checked the JavaDoc and I got told it moved to:

> org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

My code works fine so far, actually I don't want to change it... But I googled and found someone who's asking himself the same question whythe SessionFactory needs to be changed...
http://rgordon.co.uk/blog/2012/02/24/hibernate-please-dont-deprecate-yourself/

The Article is from 2012 (so not that old...) and describes everything in that way:

```
ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(properties);
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.buildServiceRegistry();

Configuration configuration = new Configuration().addClass(FeedTradePersistable.class);

SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

I implemented that. The JavaDoc proves that wrong - again! Deprecated.
It refers to:

> org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder

I googled that again. The results weren't so satisfying...

I started to modify the code...

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

And an exception is thrown...

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when
>   'hibernate.dialect' not set

at line:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

I am pretty sure this is because I haven't specified any configuration-settings. Actually, I don't want to. I feel comfortable with the hibernate.cfg.xml.

I played a bit around with configuration.addFile(.. - wasn't that successful...

Has anyone an idea about that?
Thanks

**UPDATE: (hibernate.cfg.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">qohelet</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="bonecp.setIdleMaxAgeInMinutes">240</property>
    <property name="bonecp.setIdleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes">5</property>
    <property name="bonecp.partitionCount">3</property>
    <property name="bonecp.acquireIncrement">10</property>
    <property name="bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition">60</property>
    <property name="bonecp.minConnectionsPerPartition">20</property>
    <property name="bonecp.statementsCacheSize">50</property>
    <property name="bonecp.releaseHelperThreads">3</property>
        <mapping class="order.Line" />
        <mapping class="order.Order" />
        <mapping class="order.Group" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**UPDATE (16. Feb 2014):**
I think it is necessary to show you my pom.xml as well. It took me a while until I figured out which combination of the Hibernate-Framework works for me...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Look into the `hibernate-dialect` property. It is necessary.

Comment: I know, and it's specified in the hibernate.cfg.xml already. I don't see a point why I should declare it twice.

Comment: Show us your config file.

Comment: I added the hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I got some time to modernize my software I decided to put some effort into it and did some research:

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/building-hibernate-sessionfactory-from-service-registry
provides a modern `HibernateUtil`:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
        registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();

        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);            
    }

    return sessionFactory;
}

}
```

Even though this version seems to work as well:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        sessionFactory = cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

But my problem was I didn't want to integrate a new version with the old libs. After updating I ran into a

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.injectClassLoaderDelegate(Lorg/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate;)V

often.
Annoying. Usually [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-error-initial-sessionfactory-creation-failed-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-orghibernateannotationscommonreflectionreflectionmanager/) provides good solutions, but in my case he wrote the opposite solution of [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672051/nosuchmethoderror-error-create-session-factory)...

So I searched some repositories and found a shockingly easy solution (compare: http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/):

```
<!-- HIBERNATE -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Some other minor issues which stopped me:
In the `hibernate.cfg.xml` I had to change the line from `update` to `auto`:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">auto</property>
```

Compare it to my old pom.xml... - back then I had my first "encounter" with Hibernate and added everything which seemed useful until it worked. After it did so I stopped touching it for... Almost two years... Never change a "winning" team, right?

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.12.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 12):

I think for 4.3 it's now:

```
   Configuration configuration=new Configuration()
            .configure(); // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

    // If you miss the below line then it will complaing about a missing dialect setting
    serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Comment: The main issue for this question was due to several incompatibilities within the Hibernate-Versions. It took me a while until I figured out which versions work together well.
I use Hibernate 3.6.10.Final, hibernate entity manager 3.6.10.Final, hibernate-commons-annotations 3.2.0.Final, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.1.Final.

Now I updated to 4.3.0.CR2 (only the Hibernate) to and got:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ClassLoadingException
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)

The sessionFactory assignmt

Answer (score 2):

yes, in hibernate version 4. 3 both buildSessionfactory() and ServiceRegistryBuilder() are deprecated.

so u have change your coding like below to get session factory for hibernate version 4.3

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory1();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory1() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(); // configuration
                                                                    // settings
                                                                    // from
                                                                    // hibernate.cfg.xml

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();


    serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();

    return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please post your pom.xml as well?