# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm trying to make maven aplication with database using hiberntate. And one error appears all the time when I want to use it in GUI after pressing the button.

```
  Session session =  Service.getSession();
```

here is an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:973)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
at models.Service.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:23)
at GUI.Student.RegisterOnExam.getSubjects(RegisterOnExam.java:108)
```

I tried to change dependences and hibernate.cfg.xml but it still does not work.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>Test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mainClass>main.java.Main</mainClass>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ORACLE JDBC driver, need install yourself -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Here is a Service class which I use to begin a transaction. I tried to change it too somehow.

```
package models.Service;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class Service {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {

            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                    .configure().buildSessionFactory();

    }
    public static Session getSession()
            throws HibernateException {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

}
```

It seems the problem is in it but I don't think so. How can I correct my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buildSessionFactory()` in your code is deprecated for the Hibernate version you are using. You will have to fix your code. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911308/looking-for-a-not-deprecated-session-factory) explains more about the deprecated session factory.