# NoSuchMethodError error create session factory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i am trying create project with hibernate, but i have exception in row where create `session factory`, if i delete this row - project will run successful. 
I searching solving i read this article, and added dependency `hibernate-commons-annotations` but this don't solve problem

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.injectClassLoaderDelegate(Lorg/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate;)V
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:737)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.secure.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.<init>(UserDaoImpl.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
```

line is:

```
at com.secure.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.<init>(UserDaoImpl.java:20)
```

equals row in code:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

**dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1203-jdbc42</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: [article](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-error-javareflectionmanager-cannot-be-cast-to-metadataproviderinjector/)

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why you need hibernate-commons-annotations in your pom.xml?

Comment: Oh, I was inattentive when read article, there described `ClassCastException` but i have `NoSuchMethodError`

Comment: Right. Even if you had ClassCastException, this article suggest to remove hibernate-commons-annotations, not to add it.

Comment: Actually, you may want to remove this from your pom.xml, then clean your maven repostitory and reinstall your project, f.e. from command line: mvn -U clean install

Comment: maven upload need dependency?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Hibernate v3.6 the annotations classes have been merged into core. You have specified a dependency on a very old annotations jar which doesn't compile with Hibernate core 5.0.1.

Just remove the dependency on `hibernate-commons-annotations` and this should be resolved.

Comment: yes, i solve this problem when read comment by `pzeszko`, thx!