# Hibernate fails to create SessionFactory by throwing the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate and I'm trying to run some programs in Eclipse IDE. I have searched enough for this question and I could not find answer which satisfied my case. I am not using any build tools like maven or any dependecy xml fils.

The HibernateUtil.java looks like this

```
package com.hibernate;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class HibernateUtil {

    //XML based configuration
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() 
    {
        try 
        {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
            System.out.println("Hibernate Configuration loaded \n"+ config);

            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties());
            System.out.println("Hibernate serviceRegistry created \n"+ serviceRegistry);

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry.build());
            System.out.println("Hibernate Session Factory created \n"+sessionFactory);

            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() 
    {
        if(sessionFactory == null) 
            sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

and HibernateMain.java looks like this

```
package com.hibernate;
import java.util.Date;


import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.hibernate.HibernateUtil;
import com.hibernate.Employee;

public class HibernateMain 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setName("Pankaj");
        emp.setRole("CEO");
        emp.setInsertTime(new Date());

        //Get Session
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        //start transaction
        session.beginTransaction();

        //Save the Model object
        session.save(emp);

        //Commit transaction
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Employee ID="+emp.getId());

        //terminate session factory, otherwise program won't end
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

and Employee.java looks like this

```
    package com.hibernate;

import java.util.Date;

public class Employee 
{

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String role;
    private Date insertTime;

    public int getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) 
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRole() 
    {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) 
    {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Date getInsertTime() 
    {
        return insertTime;
    }

    public void setInsertTime(Date insertTime) 
    {
        this.insertTime = insertTime;
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error

```
    0 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging  - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
18 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator].
25 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccIntegrator].
36 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cache.internal.CollectionCacheInvalidator].
44 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator].
282 [main] INFO org.hibernate.Version  - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.16.Final}
284 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
332 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver  - Interpreting public/system identifier : [-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN] - [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd]
336 [main] WARN org.hibernate.orm.deprecation  - HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
336 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver  - Recognized hibernate-configuration identifier; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
343 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor  - cfg.xml document did not define namespaces; wrapping in custom event reader to introduce namespace information
Hibernate Configuration loaded 
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration@4e7dc304
672 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator].
672 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccIntegrator].
672 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cache.internal.CollectionCacheInvalidator].
673 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator].
Hibernate serviceRegistry created 
org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder@53f65459
702 [main] INFO org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialService  - HHH80000001: hibernate-spatial integration enabled : true
710 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceBinding  - Overriding existing service binding [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccService]
710 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceBinding  - Overriding existing service binding [org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialService]
711 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration  - Building session factory using provided StandardServiceRegistry
735 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator  - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory
750 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:742)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:654)
    at com.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:25)
    at com.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:41)
    at com.hibernate.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:25)
```

I have tried removing/replacing jar files from the src/lib and scr/lib/required folders, but nothing seems to work.

I have the following Jar files under src/lib/required folder

```
antlr-2.7.7
classmate-1.3.0
dom4j-1.6.1
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final
hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final
jandex-2.0.3.Final
javassist-3.20.0-GA
jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final
jta
persistence-api-1.0.2
slf4j-api-1.7.7
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably some jar (Possibly Hibernate) version mismatch

Comment: yes, 100 % jar version mismatch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchMethodError error create session factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672051/nosuchmethoderror-error-create-session-factory)