# Fresh Hibernate 4 documentation?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

Official Hibernate documentation contains a lot of deprecated features, like here

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/quickstart/en-US/html_single/#d5e57

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application
    sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
            .buildSessionFactory();
}
```

while `buildSessionFactory()` is deprecated.

Where to get fresh Hibernate 4 documentation and quick examples?

**UPDATE**

Another example:

[image]

Here wee see as the author was suddenly killed while writing "... shows a Person class with a..." Babah!

Comment: This topic was already covered on Stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621906/is-buildsessionfactory-deprecated-in-hibernate-4

Answer (score 0):

You should build your session factory in this way:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```

You can find more detail here: http://www.javabeat.net/session-factory-hibernate-4/