# Retrieve object from hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I'm starting out in Hibernate and following a tutorial from [javabrains](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FV1yv7fvDQ). But the `buildsessionfactory` seems to be deprecated. I searched and found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8830848/3009075).

However, when i try to get object from the database, I get `NullPointerException` at sysout at last line and no entry is even saved into the database. But if i comment out the object retrieving section it works fine and saves to database.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
    public class HibernateTest {
        private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

        private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("User's name");
        user.setAddress("Chingeltei");
        user.setJoinedDate(new Date());
        user.setDescription("Description of the user");

        Session session = configureSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

  //    user = null;
  //    session = configureSessionFactory().openSession();
  //    session.beginTransaction();
  //    user = (UserDetails) session.get(UserDetails.class, 1);

  //    System.out.println("User name retreived is: "+user.getUserName());

        }

    }
```

UserDetails.java

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity 
@Table (name="user_details")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @Column (name="userid")
    private int userId;
    @Column (name="username")
    private String userName;
    @Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date joinedDate;
    private String address;
    @Transient
    private String description;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public Date getJoinedDate() {
        return joinedDate;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
    return description;
    }
    public void setUserId(int aUserId) {
        userId = aUserId;
    }
    public void setUserName(String aUserName) {
        userName = aUserName;
    }
    public void setJoinedDate(Date aJoinedDate) {
        joinedDate = aJoinedDate;
    }
    public void setAddress(String aAddress) {
        address = aAddress;
    }
    public void setDescription(String aDescription) {
        description = aDescription;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see `UserDetails.java`?

Comment: I've added it. anything ?

Comment: Not sure about this, but try `sessionFactory.openSession()` rather than second call of `configureSessionFactory()` (where you commented out at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the tutorial states, you should create `sessionFactory` once per application. So, instead of second call to `configureSessionFactory()` you should be using `sessionFactory` reference which already exists.