# can i have 2 configuration bdd of Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

i develop a *J2EE* application with **Hibernate**, and i want to have 2 database, the first will be local (in client computer ), and the second will be in the server.
indeed ,  i want to configure hibernate to connect in the local databases when the global is not accessible. 
My actual config file :
    `<hibernate-configuration >
    <session-factory>
    <property name= "hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name= "hibernate.connection.driver_class"> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/serverBdd </property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> 
    <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <mapping resource="hibernateConfiguration/Usine.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernateConfiguration/Produit.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernateConfiguration/Machine.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernateConfiguration/Operation.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernateConfiguration/Utilisateur.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>`

how Can i do this ? and if i can't what should i do to solve my problem ? 
thanks

Comment: Create two .cfg file and create two different sessionFactory object for client computer and another one for server.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but i must have one config file , and my application will read it automatically, i do : 
 factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); // to create a factory, so i did not specify the location of .cfg file :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, [here](http://www.javabeat.net/configuring-multiple-databases-in-hibernate/) you can find an example that writes in 2 databases at same time, but with a simple if condition you can decide which to use:

First, create 2 `hibernate.cfg.xml` files as usual but with different names

- serverconfig.cfg.xml
- localconfig.cfg.xml

After, in your `DAO` or wherever you get your hibernate `Session` simply check if server database and if  it is not available use local configuration:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("serverconfig.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

if (sessionFactory == null)
    sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("localconfig.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

Also, if you use Hibernate 4 or later [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621906/is-buildsessionfactory-deprecated-in-hibernate-4)

Comment: Oh thank u very much, i think that  solve my problem :)