# Hibernate 5 :- org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I am getting the error message `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity` when i am trying to integrate hibernate 5.0 with mysql

This seems to be an issue with hibernate5.0.0 and 5.0.1 . This works fine with hibernate 4.3.9

#### Maven dependices

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
```

#### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/SampleDB
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping class="UserA.User"></mapping>

</session-factory>
```

#### HibernateMain.java code

```
package UserA;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Map;
import org.hibernate.metadata.ClassMetadata;
import org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry sr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        SessionFactory sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);




        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setUserName("Arpit");
        user1.setUserMessage("Hello world from arpit");
        user1.setUserId(22);

        Session ss = sf.openSession();
        ss.beginTransaction();
        // saving objects to session
        ss.save(user1);
        ss.getTransaction().commit();
        ss.close();

    }

}
```

#### User.java

```
package UserA;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="User_table")
public class User {
    @Id
    int userId;
    @Column(name = "User_Name")
    String userName;

    @Column(name = "User_Message")
    String userMessage;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserMessage() {
        return userMessage;
    }

    public void setUserMessage(String userMessage) {
        this.userMessage = userMessage;
    }

}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: UserA.User
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1447)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGener

Answer (score 31):

I have fixed the same issue with Hibernate 5. There is a problem in this code

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure();

ServiceRegistry sr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
    configuration.getProperties()).build();

SessionFactory sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);
```

This code works fine for Hibernate 4.3.5, but the same code has the same issue for Hibernate 5.

When you do `configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr)`, using Hibernate 5, `Configuration` losts all information about mapping that gets by call `configuration.configure()`.

**Solution**

To fix the issue, if you use standard configuration files `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `hibernate.properties`, you can create the session factory by this way (without `ServiceRegistry`)

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

**Loading properties**

If you have properties in a file other then `hibernate.properties`, you can build session factory using `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder` (anyway, if you have `hibernate.properties` and other file, it will be loaded both)

To load properties as a resource

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
    configure().loadProperties("hibernate-h2.properties").build();
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

You need to have `hibernate-h2.properties` in the class path (root of the sources folder, resources folder). You can specify a path from the root source folder too
`/com/github/xxx/model/hibernate-h2.properties`.

To load properties from a path in the file system

```
File propertiesPath = new File("some_path");
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
    configure().loadProperties(propertiesPath).build();
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

You can find an example console application using this approach here [fluent-hibernate-mysql](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate-mysql). It uses a utility class to build the session factory from the [fluent-hibernate library](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate).

**Incorrect Hibernate 5 tutorial**

There is an incorrect example in Hibernate 5 tutorial [1.1.6. Startup and helpers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-firstapp-helpers). It uses this code

```
 return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build() );
```

It doesn't do a proper configuration.

Comment: You saved my life :)

Comment: every time I upgrade hibernate, my code works every each time.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  And it cut down on all the extra code! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

In Hibernate 5, you need to build `StandardServiceRegistry` and `Metadata` to build `SessionFactory`. You could use the following `HibernateUtil` to build `SessionFactory`. `hibernate.cfg.xml` should be in the root of the classpath of your application.

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder() .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } 
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Also, If you're using Hibernate 5 and using `@Id` as your identifier generation strategy then using `GenerationType.AUTO` will pick up the "sequence" identity generator by default with MySQL, which will give you an the `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'SampleDB.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist` exception, if you don't have it configured in your entities at identifier attributes. So with Hibernate 5, use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add a configuration file

```
configuration.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#configure-- the configure() method without parameter assumes a file hibernate.cfg.xml needs to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. That did not help me. I have already tried this

Comment: This is a bug in 5.0 Hibernate. I have verified that the code works fine with 4.3.9 but breaks in 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have created mapping file User.hbm.xml or User.xml file and included that file in hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Thanks a lot Chetan. I was under the impression that User.hbm.xml  is not required for hibernate 5.0 as i am using the annotations.  I will also try your solution .

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

instead of this:

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

Session session = factory.openSession();
```

solved the issue with Hibernate 5.2.10.Final.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue & I searched for almost 2 hours and tried with different possible ways like replacing old hibernate jars&changing the db table schema. But finally got the solution as below;

```
 //This line to be replaced with below commented line
 SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Replace above for

```
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
ServiceRegistry servReg = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(servReg);
```

It will then work fine..