# Loading mapping file Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm having problems when loading a mapping file from the hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
  <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The mapping file is not getting loaded in the `SessionFactory`

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown
>   entity: com.test.dto.User

but if i add the mapping manually in the `Configuration` instance:

```
static {
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure().addResource("User.hbm.xml");

        ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(registry);

    }
```

The mapping works correctly..., any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405031/hibernate-5-org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity/32711654#32711654). You can't mix configurations with `new Configuration().configure()` and `config.buildSessionFactory(registry)`. You should do all configuration with `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`. 
Something like this

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
    configure().build();
SessionFactory sessionFactory= new Configuration().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Comment: @DGomez I am very glad :)