# Hibernate 5.0.7 Configuration: entity not loaded

Tags: hibernate, configuration, annotations, entity, sessionfactory

I'm using Hibernate 5.0.7 and I've a problem with annotation configuration.

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=mydb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">sa</property>

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="com.domain.Person"/>

</session-factory>
```

I configure the session factory in this way:

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    return sessionFactory;
```

When I try to execute a query on Person class I obtained an empty list. I discovered that the class Person is not loaded properly in the session factory (sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata() returns empty list) and the only way to do that is to add manually the class:

```
 configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Person.class);
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your session factory configuration is [incorrect for Hibernate 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711654/3405171).
When you do `configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry)`, `Configuration` lost all information about mapping that gets by call `configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")`.

If you use Hibernate 5, you can create a session factory by this way

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

You don't need to pass `hibernate.cfg.xml` to the `configure()` method because of this name is used by default, so `configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")` is the same as `configure()`.

Comment: Perfect!! Solved! Thank you!

Comment: @cb2783 You are welcome. Mark my answer as accepted, please.