# Issue in Debuging Maven Java Application in Netbeans

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, mssql-jdbc, hibernate.cfg.xml

I am working on a Netbeans Maven Java Application in Netbeans. I am working on Hibernate I got these errors. I used `hibernate.cfg.xml` as Hibernate configuration and defined `sqljdbc4` driver of sql server in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. My question is, Is there any issue with MSSQL Driver or any issue with dependencies or with hibernate.cfg.xml?

My hibernate.cfg.xml contains following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver
    </property>    
    <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDatabase;
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      sa
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      abdullah242
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>    
    <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
    <mapping class="com.infiniteskills.data.entities.Customers" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

****Compiled results****

1. **Scanning for projects...**

---

### ***Building hibernate-course 1.0-SNAPSHOT***

```
***The POM for com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0 is missing, no dependency information available***

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ hibernate-course ---

 1. DEBUG - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
---
---
---
---

WARN - HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
WARN - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.Application.main(Application.java:9)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 15 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.infiniteskills.data.Application.main(Application.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There was an error building the factory
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:22)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
    ... 1 more
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.019s
Finished at: Fri Feb 05 09:21:47 PKT 2016
Final Memory: 6M/109M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project hibernate-course: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

**For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:**
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Please, add your `HibernateUtil` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like (by line numbers in the stack trace) you use `Hibernate 5`. I can make an assumption — in the `HibernateUtil` you configure `Hibernate 5` using the way of `Hibernate 4` configuration. It is entirely incorrect, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711654/3405171) for information about configuration `Hibarnate 5`.

If my assumption is correct, the reason of the exception — `Configuration` class losts all information from `hibernate.cfg.xml`, include `hibernate.dialect`, during call `configure(serviceRegistry)`.

Comment: You are right! The issue was that I configured HibernateUtil using the way of Hibernate 4 and another mistake was that I wrote the driver_class of SQL Server incorrect. I corrected both mistakes and now it compiled. Thank you!