# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: bitronix.examples.hibernate.entities.User

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-4.x

I am getting following exception on eclipse console

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: bitronix.examples.hibernate.entities.User
```

My **hibernate.cfg.xml** is like:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bitronixH4</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping resource="bitronix/examples/hibernate/entities/User.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My **Test.java** class is like

```
package bitronix.examples.hibernate.entities;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sf1 = new Configuration()
                .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session session = sf1.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("rrr");
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

[image: My project structure]

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

EDIT: My User.java is like this

```
public class User {
private Integer id;
private String name;
//getters and setters
}
```

My User.hbm.xml is like this

```
<hibernate-mapping >
    <class name="bitronix.examples.hibernate.entities.User" table="test_user" >
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Show us the Java code you are using to initialize Hibernate.

Comment: I dont have any Java code other than Test.java class, which I have post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, obviously, with configuration code. You create `Configuration` twice.

Just do

```
SessionFactory sf1 = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

I know, that it is deprecated in Hibernate 4. But for Hibernate 5 it is a good way. This Hibernate 4 approach will not work with Hibernate 5.

[Hibernate 5 :- org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711654/3405171)

Comment: Now I have to live with the fact I have done such a stupid mistake in my life.

Comment: @BhushanPatil Everybody can make a mistake with configuration. Hibernate has a very inconvenient API and an unclear documentation. Try to write as little code as possible. There are a lot of people here using a lot of unnecessary annotations, for an example.