# sqlite path in hibernate.cfg.xml on glassfish server

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, glassfish

I'm trying to use sqlite using hibernate. However, I've had hard time, configuring sqlite database path. Currently, my `hibernate.cfg.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:test.db</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="com.test.entity.Category"/>
        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I'm using IntelliJ. I've placed test.db in resources & in the artifacts I could see it in classes package. However, everytime I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Category is not mapped [select id from Category]
```

**Category.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category", schema = "", catalog = "")
public class Category {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String imageUrl;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "imageUrl")
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }
}
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    configuration.getProperties()).build();
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(sessionFactory == null){
            sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

I'm using Hibernate version 5.1.0

I've checked `sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata()` - it shows no class mapped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, add your `Category` and configuration code, and Hibernate version.

Comment: @v.ladynev Hey, I've updated it. Can you re-check

Comment: Please, add the code which creates a session factory.

Comment: @v.ladynev Added. Can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

You use an incorrect way of Hibernate 5 configuration.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
        configuration.getProperties()).build();
return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

In Hibernate 5, when you do `configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")` everything is configured properly. But when you do `configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry)` all configuration is lost.

Just do

```
return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Refer

[Hibernate 5 :- org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711654/3405171)