# Hibernate code giving exception while getting sessionfactory object

Tags: hibernate

```
private static SessionFactory factory; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }catch (Throwable ex) { 
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
        }
      ManageEmployee ME = new ManageEmployee();
```

This is my code. on line

```
factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

its throwing as error:

```
Failed to create sessionFactory object.java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider: Provider org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sanket.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:22)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider: Provider org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorBuilder.buildSelector(StrategySelectorBuilder.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:119)
    at com.sanket.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:19)
```

what might be the problem ? I tried to google it there is some new way to get the object but still same problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = ssrb.build();
        setFactory(configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry));
    }catch (Throwable ex) { 
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
    }
```

this is the new code as per suggestions on google.

Can someone help me with it ? I am totally new to Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a configuration code problem. This code should work well

`factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`

A problem with this class `org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl`

It is used for integration with [Infinispan](http://infinispan.org/) cache and  resides in the `hibernate-infinispan-xxx.jar` of corresponding version.

You need to add jar to the class path from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-infinispan/

Or you can remove a infinispan cache configuration from a Hibernate configuration, for an example from `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

**Update**

`new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()` code is deprecated for Hibernate 4. It is not deprecated for Hibernate 5. It is funny that your second variant of a configuration code will not work after you fix that error:
[Hibernate 5 :- org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405031/hibernate-5-org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity/).

A reason of the error

`org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider: Provider org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl not found`

that `java.util.ServiceLoader` can't load a class `org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl`

You can check this class by adding this code before the configuration code

```
 URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResource(
    "org/hibernate/cache/infinispan/StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl.class");
System.out.println(url);
```

You have a console application with the `main()` method and have a jar in the `WEB-INF/lib`, it is strange.

Comment: My hibernate version is 5.1.0. And I have seen many answers regarding the code 

factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

this has been deprecated and the new lines I mentioned are used now.

and I already have that jar in my lib folder under WEB-INF.

Comment: @PrithiviRaj You need to have `org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl ` class in the class path. Or you need to find something, that adds `infinispan` cache and remove it.