# Testing Hibernate mapping : no persistent classes found for query classes

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am creating a simple application using Hibernate JPA (annotations) and MySQL.I keep getting a:
    `WARN: HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: from 
     tn.ensi.cloudtrustproject.dao.entity.Country`

when testing the Hibernate mapping.

I could not locate the problem so far. Please any help.

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property 
name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

<property name= 
"hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
<property name= 
"hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/TrustCloud</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name= 
"hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider 
</property>
<property name= "hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<mapping class="tn.ensi.cloudtrustproject.dao.entity.Country" ></mapping>
<mapping class="tn.ensi.cloudtrustproject.dao.entity.CloudUser"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is HibernateUtil:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory= buildSessionFactory();
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
private static Session session=null;
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){

    try{
    Configuration configuration= new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("config/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    serviceRegistry=new 
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder(). 
    applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    return configuration.buildSessionFactory (serviceRegistry);
    }
    catch (Throwable ex){

        System.err.println("Failed to cerate SessionFactory object"+ ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static Session openSession(){
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
    public static Session getCurrentSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     }

    public static void close(){
     sessionFactory.close();
     }
     }
```

The class Test.java:

```
package tn.ensi.cloudtrustproject.util;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;


public class Test {

static Session session= HibernateUtil.openSession();
public static void main(String[] args) {

    session.createQuery("from tn.ensi.cloudtrustproject.dao.entity.Country 
").list();

}

}
```

The  entity class:

```
package tn.ensi.cloudtrustproject.dao.entity;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="country")
public class Country implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id @GeneratedValue 
@Column(name="countryid")
private Integer countryId ;

@Column(name="countrydes")
private String countryDes;



public Country(Integer countryId, String countryDes) {
    super();
    this.countryId = countryId;
    this.countryDes = countryDes;
}
public Country() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Integer getCountryId() {
    return countryId;
}
public void setCountryId(Integer countryId) {
    this.countryId = countryId;
}
public String getCountryDes() {
    return countryDes;
}
public void setCountryDes(String countryDes) {
    this.countryDes = countryDes;
}
public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Country [countryId=" + countryId + ", countryDes=" + countryDes
            + "]";
}
}
```

The project: 
[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCboI.png)

The table is created:

[Table country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR43Z.png)

Comment: The entity class is truncated. Where do you define table mapping for the entity?

Comment: Try session.createQuery("from Country 
").list(); instead of setting the full path

Comment: @StanislavL  I have defined the mapping in hibernate.cfg.xml and you can  find below the entity class coomplete

Comment: @kimy82   I have changed before many times but I usually get the error: Country is not mapped I have used anso the code `from tn.ensi.cloudtrustproject.dao.entity.class.getName()` but it does not work

Comment: @ManelPhD Please, provide the Hibernate version. Do you use Hibernate 5?

Comment: @v.ladynev I use hibernate5.2.10

Comment: @ManelPhD You can find a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32711654/3405171

Answer (score 0):

you have mentioned configuration file exists in `config/hibernate.cfg.xml`. Please check whether it is existing in same location.

Comment: Yes. You can see here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCboI.png