# Error when I run simple hibernate demo application

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

I write a simple hibernate application, but when I run I have this error

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityListeners
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at hibernatedemopart1.Util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:35)
    at hibernatedemopart1.HibernateDemoPart1.main(HibernateDemoPart1.java:23)
```

This, is my HibernateUtil class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package hibernatedemopart1.Util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;



/**
 *
 * @author phate
 */
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry; 
//    private static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    static{
        try{
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();

            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }catch(Throwable ex){
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed: " + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError();
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

I don't understand where is the error. Initially in my HibernateUtil class I used this code

```
...
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
...
```

but I see that it is deprecated so I decided to use the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621906/is-buildsessionfactory-deprecated-in-hibernate-4)

Comment: which hibernate version of library you using?

Comment: The version integrated in Netbeans 8. I think is 4.3

Comment: Ok, mea culpa. I forgot this line in hibernate configuration file:         `<!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>`

Comment: I have also added this library (integrated in Netbeans) Hibernate 4.3.x(JPA2.1)

Comment: can you please confirm `hibernate-jpa` jar available in runtime scope?

Comment: i'm not sure I understand your question, but without the library `Hibernate 4.3.x(JPA2.1)` linked in my project, I have an error when I run the code