# Spring & Hibernate without jpa

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

For my new project I plan to use Hibernate 5 and Spring 4 and as always like to separate into different layers / projects.

**Gradle dependencies:**

```
"org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.1.RELEASE",
"org.springframework:spring-orm:4.2.1.RELEASE",
'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.2.Final',
'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
```

There is an API project, that contains a User.class. From my opinion this user class must not use any annotations for a database layer. It must not specify `@Table(name = "users")` or other things. It should be a simple Objects with getters and setters.

The database layer should decide how to store the data and this depends strongly on the database (e.g. MongoDB or MySQL).

I followed some tutorials for Hibernate and ended up with the following `@Configuration` class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("de.pentos.proto")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);

    private static Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        // properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put("hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        return properties;
    }

    {
        log.debug("Here am I: {}");
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Inject
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(final DataSource dataSource) {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Inject
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(final SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        final HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
                sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

It works very well, except it uses an annotated class.

How can I add my `hbm/user.xml` to the sessionBuilder?

I tried with `Configuration` class, that I found in some examples, but the Method `buildSessionFactory()` is deprecated.

I also tried the `ServiceRegistry` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621906/is-buildsessionfactory-deprecated-in-hibernate-4) but then lost my datasource approach and without the datasource the system was not able to setup the `HibernateTransactionManager`.
Without `HibernateTransactionManager` I was not able to use `@Transactional` and I don't like to open and close me transactions manually.

Currently I'm spinning in circles and really need help to get it to work. I already thought about throwing Hibernate away and use my good old MyBatis approach, but you know, I like to learn something new...

Comment: Why you want to load ```hbm/user.xml```?

Comment: because it contains the xml description of the data mapping for the user object, because the user object must not contain JPA annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `xml` files as a resource to `SessionFactory`, as follows:

```
@Inject
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(final DataSource dataSource) {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.addResource("/path-to-/hbm/user.xml");
        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }
```