# How can I resolve "overrides a deprecated API" for Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I built an `java class` for I can use `Hibernate`. When I select the `NetBeans`option: "`clean and build`", the system indicate me the next problem:

```
Note: /home/.../NewHibernateUtil.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

This is my class NewHibernateUtil:

```
package bean.utilitaria;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class NewHibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

How I can correct this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't it give you more details? Like: What exactly is the deprecated API? And usually the javadoc of a deprecated method/class should tell you what to use instead.

Comment: Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621906/is-buildsessionfactory-deprecated-in-hibernate-4