# Hibernate error(Cant build session factory)

Tags: hibernate

I am getting

> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling
>   Driver#connect in my navigator application upgraded to WAS 8.5.5.5

In WAS 8.0 it worked, but after upgrading to WAS 8.5.5, I'm getting the above error.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
ServiceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
```

FYI,am getting error here

```
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Comment: Hibernate session factory configuration has been changed at ~4 Hibernate version, your HibernateUtil might be deprecated

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/10784731/3019024

Comment: Hi Dev, could u please refer updated one

Comment: As far I know, the comment above is

Comment: what version of hibernate is compatible in WAS 8.5.5.5?

Comment: I'm not familiar  with WAS, but according to the error it's possibly already uses Hibernate 4+